# Should I use "on", "into", or "onto" in the following sentence?

Tags: prepositions

> I bite the gingerbread man and his head rolls **on/into/onto** my
>   tongue.

What the correct preposition? I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**into** is not appropriate because we normally only use it when something goes inside something else or is pressed firmly against a surface, possibly changing the shape of the surface. For your sentence, **into** would be OK if you were to say:

> I bite the gingerbread man and his head rolls **into** my mouth.

We use **on** when something is in contact with something or makes contact with it.

We use **onto** only when something makes contact with something.

For most verbs, it is sufficient to use **on** even when something makes contact with something. In the following examples, we could use **onto**, but the verb makes it clear that the books and the plate are making contact, so **on** is sufficient:

> Put the books **on** the table
>   The plate fell **on** the floor.

With **roll** (and **move**), the situation is different. In the following sentence, the ball could already be on the floor and be rolling along the surface, or it could have rolled off something else and made contact with the floor.

> The ball rolled **on** the floor

If we want to make it clear that the ball was somewhere else, then it rolled and made contact with the floor, we would use **onto**:

> The ball rolled [from the table] **onto** the floor.

If, on the other hand, we wanted to indicate that the ball were already on the floor, we would use **on**.

This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rolled%20on%20the%20floor%2C%20rolled%20onto%20the%20floor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crolled%20on%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crolled%20onto%20the%20floor%3B%2Cc0) shows that **on** is more widely used than **onto** but **onto** is becoming increasingly common. If you look at some of the individual instances of each phrase in the past 20 years, you will see a clear distinction in meaning, as described above, between **rolled on the floor** and **rolled onto the floor**.

With the head of the cookie, the only one that really works in this situation, where the head rolls and makes contact with the tongue, is:

> I bite the gingerbread man and his head rolls **onto** my tongue.

Comment: @alex: archaic? Not at all. Look at the NGram that I have added: usage of **onto** was steadily increasing until 2000.

Comment: @alex - I think you might be confusing _unto_ with _onto_. I’d agree that _unto_ has a more archaic feel. [Interesting supplemental ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=onto%2Cunto&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 1):

I can see why a learner might think *into* would be a good candidate. Here’s one dictionary definition (from NOAD):

> **into** (*prep.*) expressing movement or action with the result that someone or something makes physical contact with something else : *he crashed into a parked car*

However, in this case, the example usage provided by the dictionary gives a good indication of the context how this is usage is typically seen – with some kind of *forceful* contact. You often see this in the context of sports: a race car may slam *into* the wall, a rugby player may crash *into* a ball carrier.

Similarly, [American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=into) lists this definition:

> **into** (*prep.*) Against: *crashed into a tree*.

In the case of a gingerbread man being eaten and the head *rolling* into the mouth, there is simply not enough force for *into* be the right choice. That said, something like this would be fine:

> I pressed the gingerbread man’s head into my tongue and took a bite.

because *press* implies more force than *rolls*.

In your sentence, I think *onto* is the best choice:

> I bite the gingerbread man and his head rolls onto my tongue.

because *onto* can be used when something moves to a location on the surface of something.

One other note, *into* is appropriate when something goes to an enclosed area (into the room, into the cave, for example). So, *into* would be appropriate if you changed *tongue* to *mouth*:

> I bite the gingerbread man and his head rolls into my mouth.

Answer (score 0):

"Onto", but I'm curious if this is something you would say in *any* language, since when you bite a cookie the piece you bite off wouldn't really *roll* anywhere inside your mouth.  Instead it kind of just lays there until you chew it up.

A more natural way to say something like:

> I bite *off* the head of the gingerbread man and let it rest **on** my tongue.

Answer (score -1):

Your choice is either *on* or *onto*, *into* would not be appropriate since it probably does not penetrate your tongue.

Comment: Actually I don't think on is a good choice either.

Comment: Who says _into_ requires "penetration"? A hockey player can get checked [into](http://6abc.com/sports/bieber-gets-checked-into-boards-by-fmr-flyers-captain/1726485/) the boards; an outfielder's body can slam [into](http://www.bostonherald.com/sports/red_sox/clubhouse_insider/2016/06/blake_swihart_exits_red_sox_game_with_ankle_injury) the fence, and a tongue depressor can be pressed [into](http://apil.arizona.edu/baker/pubpres/Dissertation.pdf) the tongue (p.27).

Comment: J.R. makes valid points about *into*, but I still feel like it's inappropriate in the case of gingerbread/tongue.  All of those uses of *into* still imply some kind of forceful pressing, which doesn't sound like what a piece of gingerbread rolling on/into/onto your tongue does.

Comment: @J.R. Are you saying if I told you "The knife was pushed **into** his tongue." you would understand it to mean "The knife was **on** his tongue?" Your use of *into the boards*, *into the fence* and *into the tongue* work because there is a boundary or surface onto which contact is made, and from experience one knows a tongue depressor does not cut one's tongue also the context of "pressed" is different than "pushed".

Comment: @Peter - A knife is quite different from a piece of a cookie. And it depends on the verb. If I was eating my dinner and holding a butter knife, _pressed into_ would not imply penetration, but if it was a steak knife, _cut into_ probably would.

Comment: @J.R. it could be a sharp cookie...

Comment: @J.R. That's bit unfair, for ELLers to follow your line of reasoning, they would have to understand the implication of a **butter knife** (not sharp)  and **pressed** (against) and **tongue** (malleable), if instead "a butterknife was *pressed into a bar of butter" would it not imply *penetration*?", since a butter bar is very soft no matter the object used against it.

Comment: What’s “unfair” to a learner is what you said: “_into_ would not be appropriate since it probably does not penetrate your tongue.” The way I read that, it implies _into_ would never be a proper preposition to use sans some kind of penetration, which simply isn’t true. I’ve seen that kind of statement on ELL before, answers like, “You wouldn’t use _on_ unless it was on top of something.” That’s inane; prepositions usually have multiple meanings, and they shouldn’t be trivialized as if they have only one. My dictionary lists 9 for _into_ with #1 indicating penetration, and #2 physical contact.

Comment: @stangdon - I never said _into_ was the right preposition to use. I merely wanted to correct the erroneous reason given – it’s not because the gingerbread “probably does not penetrate” the tongue.